# How to apply rotations for seperate object's axis?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, transforms

I have recently stuck up on problem where I have to set object's x and y rotation to 0.0, but keep z rotation equal to the current one (best way- don't affect at all). How to do that?

I was thinking of something similar to that what I used for other data(`own.worldOrientation[0] = 0.0`), but it didn't appear to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

#Set orientation to euler!
orientation = own.worldOrientation.to_euler()
#Set up orientation of each axis
orientation.x = 0.0
#Apply rotation
own.worldOrientation = orientation
```

Here is the code that resolves the problem! It absolutely works